# An imported package is an object of what kind?

Tags: r

I'm new to R, so please don't blast me.

I'm trying to deeply understand how the R machinery works. Since i want to import a dataset in R i discovered the function `read.table()`, which works correctly.

table() is a function, and everything happens in R is due to functions. But that `read`, is a package or an object ? Also, since packages are NOT objects and in R everything that exist is a object, is still possible to invoke a package in R command line ?

Comment: I come from Java and C...

Comment: Anyway, are they situated in some predefined package and loaded at runtime?

Comment: ps: is it also possible that classes' names are written low case ?

Comment: ps2: why in environment call with a function as argument the () are not needed ?

Comment: Referring to the class name question. I found in the documentation classes written in lowercase, but isn't this a bad practice ?

Comment: To clarify, `read.table` is just the actual name of the function. It is not the `table` function from the `read` package, that would be `read::table`. nor is the `read` method for an object of class `table`. The latter could actually be possible, but in this case it is not. The `.` in a function name can therefore be ambiguous (see dupe link), and one the reasons some people prefer to use `_`, as in `read_table`.

Comment: _"Also, since packages are NOT objects and in R everything that exist is a object, is still possible to invoke a package in R command line?"_ Packages are environments, not sure what you mean with "invoke". You can attach a package with `library(package)`, or access objects in the package directly using `package::object`.

Comment: @Axeman "Packages are environments" That is not correct. Each package has an associated environment.

Comment: @Roland, thanks for the clarification.